# ASP.NET Core EF Migration Error: No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2017

When I want to add Entity Framework migration to my ASP.NET Core 1.1 by run "dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate" get this error

> "No executable found matching command "dotnet-ef"".

After google this error i wanted to add Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet Package to project but in console get this:

> "Install-Package : Package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet
>   1.0.1' has a package type 'DotnetCliTool' that is not supported by project"

and this is project.json:

{   "tools": { "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.1"   } }

What should I do exactly to enable migration in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `project.json` tooling never RTMed. You should upgrade to [Visual Studio 2017](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/) (and the [.NET Core SDK 1.0.4](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core)).

If you really want to continue using `project.json`, it should look like this (But realize it's unsupported)

```
{
    "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.1",
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": {
            "version": "1.1.1",
            "type": "build"
        }
    },
    "tools": {
        "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.0.0-preview4-final"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the version to 2.0.2 for "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" should work

Comment: more like a comment than an answer